# How small $2^n$ could be in the case $0< n<0.5$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

What is the the smallest number of $2^n$ ,  in the case $0< n<0.5$?

It would be always greater than $1$ but how I can prove that?

Comment: What's the derivative of $2^n$?

Comment: @MikeSQ I believe that was meant to be a hint for the OP, encouraging thought along the lines of Yves Daoust's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no smallest value of $2^n$ for $0 < n < \frac{1}{2}$.

Suppose that there was a $t$ such that $0 < t < \frac{1}{2}$ with the desired property. Now, note that we have $0 < \frac{t}{2} < \frac{1}{2}$ and hence $2^{\frac{t}{2}} <2^t$, a contradiction.

And yes, you are correct, since $0 < n < \frac{1}{2} \implies 2^0 < 2^n < 2^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: @MikeSQ but it will not get a minimum ("smallest number") as it is an open interval

Comment: @gbox , I got that mate!

Answer (score 2):

An exponential function is monotonous, hence

$$0<n<\frac12\implies 1<2^n<\sqrt2.$$